# Slice layer : how to discard one sliced output that will not be used in further layers?

Tags: caffe

My network has multiple losses. I would like to test only a certain loss.

I have sliced softmax into softmax_1 and softmax_2, and only softmax_1 is used for this certain loss.

```
### slice softmax into softmax_1: Nx6xHxW, softmax_2: Nx1xHxW
layer {
  name: "slice_conv1_1_D"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "softmax"
  top: "softmax_1"
  top: "softmax_2"
  slice_param
  {
    slice_dim: 1
    slice_point: 6
  }
}
```

However, running the network with the slice layer above made the network produced tons of softmax_2 values, as they are not used by other layers.

Are there any ways that I can slice my data "softmax" and keep only "softmax_1" and discard "softmax_2" completely?

Thank you very much for your help.

Added:
I know I might set loss_weight for other losses to be 0. However, I don't want to consider that options due to the computation resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SilenceLayer](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/silence.html) is exactly what you're looking for - it's a special "do nothing" layer that only takes inputs but does not produce any output, keeping your log clean:

`layer {
  name: "silence"
  type: "Silence"
  bottom: "softmax_2"
}`